# Context is refreshing but could not able to get the instance of declared bean

Tags: java, spring

Trying to run simple spring code, getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.
Defined a class in beans.xml with id - "sayHelloImpl".
Created applicationContext of ClassPathXmlApplicationContext class and provided a path to the beans.xml file. When invoking .getBean("sayHelloImpl") getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.

> beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

<bean id="sayHelloImpl" class = "com.Impl.SayHelloImpl"></bean>

</beans>
```

> SayHelloImpl.java file

```
package com.Impl;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.Interface.SayHello;

@Service("sayHelloImpl")
public class SayHelloImpl implements SayHello {
    @Override
    public String helloSpring() {
        System.out.println("inside helloSpring()");
        return "Hello Spring 4.1.7";
    }
}
```

> Main.java file

```
package com.Main;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.Interface.SayHello;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath*:beans.xml");

    SayHello hello = (SayHelloImpl) applicationContext
            .getBean("sayHelloImpl");

    System.out.println(hello.helloSpring());
    }
}
```

After executing this main file I am getting below exception on console,

```
Jan 14, 2018 4:51:15 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@5d099f62: startup date [Sun Jan 14 16:51:15 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sayHelloImpl' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
at com.Main.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Comment: Is bean.xml in **src/main/resources** folder?

Comment: Its in src/main/beans.xml

Comment: move it in src/main/resources folder

Comment: Tried.. did not work.. Showing the same exception

Comment: Do you have config resources folder ? <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

Comment: Its working when I moved the file in "source folder" at src/ main/resources.Thanks man..!